# Can't access web services via IP but through the host names it does

Tags: apache, web-services, networking

I'm using a server 2008 r2. There I've installed Wamp on `port 8080, SSRS on port 8063` and Some IIS sites on various ports.

I've installed CCproxy on the same server.

The funny thing is, I can't access them via server `IP:port (192.168.8.100:8080)` But I can, however, access it by `Host:port (Mainserver:8080)`.

Then I thought it might be a clash between those services and installed wamp on a windows 8.1 computer and even that I can't access via the IP.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are trying to access your website by using the local IP range `192.168.1.100`. In some WAMP default configs, the devs have set the apache config to disallow access except from localhost.

1. Try to open the `httpd.conf` file located at 
   `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache#.#.#\conf\httpd.conf`
2. Find the `<Directory "c:/wamp/www">` block and replace the `Order Deny,Allow` and everything that follows with `Order Allow,Deny` followed by `Allow from all`. The end result should look like something similar to this:

   ```
   DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
   <Directory "c:/wamp/www">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       Order Allow,Deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>
   ```
3. To be safe, look into the virtual hosts config file and see if you find any `Order Deny,Allow` directives and replace them as well. The file is located at `C:\wamp\bin\Apache#.#.#\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`

You can read more about Order Directive from the [Apache Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#order)

Comment: I've already set up those to allow from my IP Range. Strange thing is, it applies to all my web services. Not just wamp..